# Creating a segue for a TableViewController cell's detail accessory button

Tags: ios7, storyboard, uitableview, segue

I'm trying to implement segueing from a tableview controller when the user taps the cell's accessory button.

I've searched on here and have some new things to try but I just wanted to ask whether in the storyboard you can actually create the segues from the accessory button, or whether you just need to create them from the tableviewcontroller.

It'll be within the accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath that I'll want to act on the tap, but I see some answers on here say that you have to just go from the tableviewcontroller when creating your segues where as another answer said that the sender within prepare for segue would be set to the cell that contains your accessory view.

Whenever I try to ctrl drag from the accessory button in my prototype cell it just gets rid of the already existing on-selected segue I'd setup for that cell.

Just wanted to know for sure, what the best practice was before I started making all my detail accessory segues just go from the root TableViewController and passing through accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath's indexPath (or it's row) as the sender to my prepareForSegue.

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detail Disclosure Button and Segues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087389/detail-disclosure-button-and-segues)

Comment: @jason Thanks yes, this is one of the questions I found with my searching. It was so old though I didn't know how much had changed with later versions of iOS. 

In particular this much more recent question 

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680828/unable-to-segue-using-an-accessory-indicator

was answered with 

"However, the sender argument in prepareForSegue:sender: will be the cell that the accessory button is contained in."

Which confused me, as this sort of implied that it was possible to create a segue from the accessory button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after trying the suggestions I described in my original question I got the code all working how I wanted. I added segues from the root tableview controller and then performed them programatically within the accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath delegate function.

I have a few Table View Controllers doing similar things in my navigation controller so I set about implementing this accessory button workflow in each of them. When i reached the last TVC in my nav controller hierarchy I didn't want selecting cells to go any further, so i changed the accessory type to just detail.

As I wasn't concerned at this stage to have the cell interaction sourced segues overwriting each other I just dragged a segue out from the prototype cell to the destination view controller. Upon doing so within the add segue popup I saw 2 options - Selection Segue and Accessory Action. I'm sure that when I first tried doing this I only had the single Selection Segue choice.

Regardless of whether this was my tired eyes missing it, or Xcode having a funny turn (as it seems to from time to time, being laggy at updated states of various files etc) I can now say in answer to my original question, all you have to do is setup your accessory action segue as required. You can have both selection segue and accessory action segues setup from the same prototype cell, and everything just works as you'd expect.

I've just updated my setup to work this way and all seems fine.

Cheers